# Not able to using playsound module in python

Tags: python-3.x

From playsound import playsound
Playsound ('c:\mission python\play.mp3')

I've tried above code

But I'm getting error of can not find specified file.

Comment: if it does not find the specified file that means the file does not exist and make sure you escape backslashes using backslashes

Comment: use double backslash in place of single.

Answer (score 0):

you need an r before the path, so it makes your path a raw string instead of an ordinary string.

```
From playsound import playsound Playsound (r'c:\mission python\play.mp3')
```

if that doesn't work i guess try this?

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound(r'c:\mission python\play.mp3', winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

and if that bugs, try converting your file to a wav file so it's more compatible.